# How to start a script in termux from an app

Tags: android, termux

I need to start a script in a termux environment on my android tablet from an other android app. I think it should be possible in two ways.

1. setting up some kind of startup script (like the ~/.bashrc in the bash shell) in termunx and starting termux from the other app
2. calling termux from the other app with the script name as parameter, so that termux executes that script immediately.

I don't know how to do either of these possibilities. 
Does anybody know how to accomplish it, maybe with a third method, I didn't think of so far?

Comment: See here using Tasker to call a script in Termux. Tasker also passes in variables to the script parameters. 

https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/mjc4wx/android_11_wifi_adb_working_in_termux_as_a_result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see the wood for the trees. The answer is exactly my first suggested way. I didn't realize, that bash is the default shell in termux. So just one of .bashrc .profile .bash_profile do the job.

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you solved this?

Comment: just put a file named .bashrc (alternatively .profile or .bash_profile, see man bash in any unix-like system, chapter invocation, for details of the invocation of these init-scripts) in in your home directory in thermux. Edit it like any other bash script. If .bashrc exists and is executable (chmod u+x .bashrc), it is executed directly after startup of thermux. Inside the script you can set environment variables (export TEST=test), execute other programs (test_program option1 option2) or do some other bash magic.
Hope this helps